# Unique integers and their counts in a list (making a histogram)

Tags: python, algorithm

If I have a list like [10, 10, 2, 3, 1], how do I determine the unique values and the counts of each unique value? For example, the result should
tell me that the unique values are 10, 2, 3, 1 (i'm sure it would best if sorted) and then that the counts for each respective element is 2, 1, 1, 1.

My current solutions are as follows, though during an interview, the interviewer seemed to indicate these were not what he was looking for:

```
arr = [10, 10, 2, 3, 1]

# Using numpy... this is what I would actually use in practice
# could also use `np.hist` aand set the number of bins
# equal to to the number of unique elements??
unique, counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
histogram = zip(unique, counts)
```

```
# Should sort the elements of the array here... not sure
# which sorting algorithm to use and I haven't implemented
# one from scratch in a long time anyways so wouldn't know where
# to start
arr = sorting_algorithm(arr)

# Using a python dictionary
histogram = dict()
for ele in arr:
  if ele not in histogram:
    histogram[ele] = 1
  else:
    histogram[ele] += 1
```

Comment: Does this solution give the correct answer? Was the interviewer expecting you to write an algorithm yourself? In python, you could use `Counter(arr)` to solve the problem in a single line.

Comment: `for ele in arr:` and then `if ele not in arr:` will always be false. Is this a typo? Or did you actually make this mistake in the interview? Maybe this is the problem that the interviewer was worried about?

Comment: It was a typo. This certainly gives the correct answer, but the interview happened virtually, and I was unable to share my screen, so it was quite difficult to communicate what I was thinking about in terms of code as well as just understanding the problem description. My first suggestion was the use of the `np.unique` function. When it seemed that he wanted more of an explanation than that, I basically, "suggested" the use of a dictionary for a solution, but he said "you could use a dictionary, but can you think of a better solution?" I would use the `np.unique` or `np.hist` function in

Comment: practice, which is why it was my first response, especially since any data I would be working with would be `np.ndarray`, so I might as well just a `numpy` function that is optimized for such a task.

Comment: Maybe he was seeing if you know about `Counter`, depending on the exact wording of the question. If it was a code-writing exercise, then your solution seems just fine, other than the unnecessary sorting at the beginning.

Comment: One small improvement to your manual solution: you could use `defaultdict` to avoid the need for an `if` statement.

Comment: And I agree that you should use tools that are available rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes, I thought about `defaultdict` but wasn't sure which arguments to pass to initialize any new key's values to 1. Since it was interview, I wanted to give response for which I was familiar with the solution. Thank you for pointing the `defaultdict` out, though!

Comment: If you use `defaultdict`, you want the default value to be 0, not 1. This way you can always do `histogram[ele] += 1`

Comment: Note that `defaultdict` expects a function as its initialising argument, not a class. When you write for instance `histogram = defaultdict(int)`, the `int` in there is used like a function. The function that produces 0 when it's called, because `int()` is 0. If you want another default value, write your own function, for instance using a `lambda`. `weirdcounter = defaultdict(lambda: 1)`

Comment: You can avoid the `if / else` with a standard `dict` as well, using method `.setdefault`: `histogram = dict(); for ele in arr: histogram.setdefault(ele, 0); histogram[ele] += 1`

Comment: Actually you don't even need `.setdefault`. The simpler method `.get` works too. `histogram = dict(); for ele in arr: histogram[ele] = histogram.get(ele, 0) + 1`

Comment: This is great insight, @Stef, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Counter from the *collections* module.

```
from collections import Counter

arr = [10, 10, 2, 3, 1]

c = Counter(arr)

for k, v in c.items():
  print(k, v)
```

**Output: **

```
10 2
2 1
3 1
1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `collections.Counter`. Writing your own code to do this in an interview is probably not the end of the world, but I'd guess that the interviewer wasn't happy with your answer because `numpy` isn't necessary for this task.

```py
import collections

arr = [10, 10, 2, 3, 1]
counters = collections.Counter(arr)
print(counters) # Gets frequencies.
print(list(sorted((key, value) for key, value in counters.items()))) # Obtain sorted list by key value.
```

Comment: There is no need for `sorted`. `collections.Counter` already has a `.most_common()` method. Also, if you use `sorted`, you probably want to sort in decreasing order of frequencies (the ones you call "value") rather than in increasing order of "key". (the downvote is not mine)

Comment: @Stef The list is for a histogram. If you're trying to put the bars in order (of key), then sorting by frequency isn't ideal.